# How to overwrite docs from one collection to other collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have docs in collection c1, and update_dt. I want to insert all these docs from c1 to collection c2. It might be possible some docs already exists in c2 but still I want to insert updated docs to collection c2.
e.g-

```
collection c1-
doc1- { _id : 100, update_dt : "2015-10-29T15:45:00.000Z", Name: "Leo" }
Collection c2- 
doc1- { _id : 100, update_dt : "2015-10-10T15:45:00.000Z" }.
```

And I want to overwrite doc1 of collection c1 to doc1 of collection c2.
I tried but shows duplicate key error as _id field can't be same.
I want to automate this, will really appreciate your help.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Please find it. db.rap_orders.insert(db.orders.find({updated_at : {$gte :new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000*60*60*24000)}}).toArray()), here it may be possible orders collections records is already in rap_orders with same _id field, and I want to insert it in rap_orders again.